# my carousel is not working properly bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon(s) in the root directory -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.7.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--[if lt IE 8]>
            <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->

        <div class="container" style="margin-top:20px;">
        <div class="col-md-4">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
  <li class="active">
  <a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div id="mycar" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#mycar" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#mycar" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item-active">
                    <img src="slider/demo-slider-1.jpg">
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                    <img src="slider/image-slider-2.jpg">

                     </div>
                    </div>
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#mycar" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#mycar" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
            </div>


        </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

This is my full code what problem is occuring is that carousel slide is not properly functioning. When page is loaded first time the image slider works means when we click slider arrow (either of them weather left or right) it works and image does change. But after first attempt it does not change or slide the image. other problem is that slide indicator links are also not working.

Comment: what is working first time??

Comment: when i click on button picture change but after that picture does not slide

Comment: show us your click event code..

Comment: Please share enough code so we can understand what is wrong in actually ...

Comment: i have further explained the problem

Comment: Check the console for more clues .. i found some method missing issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like something is conflicting. Build the "mycar" Div as following

```
<div id="mycar" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#mycar" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#mycar" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            </ol>
            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                     <img src="slider/demo-slider-1.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="slider/demo-slider-2.jpg">
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#mycar" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a><a class="right carousel-control"
                    href="#mycar" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right">
                    </span></a>
        </div>
```

Hope this helps .. if it does help me earn reputation .. or if you seek more help please let me know.

Comment: by mistake i wrote class item-active the right syntax is item active